# The Great Boot Partition Debacle

Tags: boot, partitioning

I've been trying for about a month to solve this "boot partition full" issue and have some observations: When I look for solutions on ask ubuntu, the answers are usually quite straightforward.  When I go to the terminal to execute the solutions, things get a little hairy.

Gparted...this is not installed and when I try to use apt get, I see a message that says I have to clean up some other issues.  All of this comes from not really remembering much about dos and having to solve boot partition issues using it.

Is there a way to solve issues on Ubuntu through procedures instead of the terminal?

Is Ubuntu just too technical for my skill set?

Comment: Why did you make a separate boot partition and why did you make it so small ? Sounds like poor planning on your part especially when considering the size of modern hard drives. Second you need to manage your partitions from a live CD

Comment: This site isn't a very good fit for this kind of post, you need to have a particular question you want to ask.  May I suggest [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) once you have the reputation.

Comment: bodhi.zazen I don't think I had any input in the size of the boot partition...it was created when I installed the OS?

Comment: Neon_overload, thanks for your input.  I am trying to solve the problem and there is a question in there somewhere.  It is posed in a chatty sort of way though so I get your drift.

Comment: Ubuntu does not create a separate `/boot` partition by default. When posting questions, you must post details. For instance, you refer to solutions "get[ting] a little hairy" and "a message that says I have to clean up some other issues," but you don't post details. Cut-and-paste the output of commands that are giving you problems. You may need to post multiple questions, since those two examples alone are unrelated problems. Also, you're *not* using DOS (which is a primitive OS); you're using bash (which is a shell). Bash is commonly used in Ubuntu because it's quick and concise.

Comment: To recap, you need to ask only one question, and state it clearly, without unrelated text - as it stands you asked multiple questions here, firstly: `Is there a way to solve issues on Ubuntu through procedures instead of the terminal?` this is an unclear question, and secondly, `Is Ubuntu just too technical for my skill set?` this seems to be just frustration coming out, but it's distracting from any actual question.  You can't "hide" a question in your post, it needs to be the one and only thing that is clearly stated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gparted is installed by default in Ubuntu's LiveCD version. You should resize partitions from Live CD session.
This link might help you: [How to Partition](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowtoPartition)

Comment: I got gparted up and running using the live cd.  I couldn't resize the crypt partition so I saved off my data and reinstalled without the encryption.  The resulting partitions were a lot different:the boot partition was 110gb of 120 total.  All seems to be working, I just hope that running without encryption will keep my numbers safe.  Thanks all for your answers, I hope to be more concise with my next post.  By the way, I right clicked on the gparted and couldn't copy to paste here